# My image is not working with new class declarations

Tags: html, css, svg

I am working on responsiveness of web page, for which I am using bootstrap. The web page consists of both images and text. I am able to make both of them responsive, but when I use

`<img src="live_files/img_01.svg" class='img-responsive "stl_01"'>`,

my image is falling on the text. To avoid this I am commenting my CSS.

Is there any way to resolve the problem without commenting my CSS?

Additionally, my images are not getting displayed when I am checking in iPad and iPhone. They only display when the images are in cache.

Comment: where is your code, what you have tried yet, put it in fiddle

Comment: Welcome on SO. This is a Q/A site, not a place where magicians solve problem without seeing any code. Please [have the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page

Comment: `class='img-responsive "stl_01"'` selects the invalid class name: `.img-responsive."stl_01"`. I can not say this is causing your problems, but it is wrong anways: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-selectors

Comment: @NicoO Close, but not quite. It still selects `img-responsive`, but it fails to select the separate `stl_01` due to the additional quotes. Both are valid class names on their own, however.

Comment: thanks for the clarification @TylerH. You are right. I just wanted to make an example of what Afreen is implicitly trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have multiple quotes in HTML class declarations. In order to declare multiple classes for an HTML element, simply add a space between two classes, like so:

```
<img src="live_files/img_01.svg" class="img-responsive stl_01">
```

The moment you add additional quotes (whether they are single or double quotes), anything after that within the class declaration is disregarded.